# How does one prove inadmissibility of inference rules in First Order Logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In FOL, can we say that if from a set of assumptions gamma we have no proof of A, then we have a proof of not-A ($\Gamma \vdash \neg A$)?

Additionally, are these rules admissible as part of a first order proof system:

a) $\frac {\Gamma \vdash \forall x(Ax \rightarrow Bx)}{\Gamma, \{ \neg B\} \vdash \forall x \neg A}$

b) $\frac {\Gamma \vdash \forall x(Ax \rightarrow Bx)}{\Gamma, \{ \neg B\} \vdash \exists x \neg A}$

My intuition is that (a) is clearly inadmissible and (b) is admissible, but I don't know whether my reasoning is clear enough.

As I see it, (a) is inadmissible because it would go against the normal interpretation of material implication. If we have $A \rightarrow B$ = True and B = False, it would mean A is false. But I don't know whether this type of semantic reasoning can be applied to proving the inadmissibility of a syntactical proof or not. I'm having difficulty not appealing to the meanings of the logical constants and trying to be fully syntactical.

Comment: You have the predicates with monovariate arguments in the top lines, but they are invariate in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question, the answer is no: a sentence in FOL can hold in some models but not in all models. E.g., $\forall x, y(x = y)$ holds iff the universe has exactly one element and is therefore neither provable nor disprovable. There are first-order axiom systems $\Gamma$ such that for every formula $A$ either $\Gamma \vdash A$ either $\Gamma \vdash \lnot A$, but such systems (which are called *complete*) are quite special: one example would be to take $\Gamma$ to be $\{\forall x, y(x = y)\}$ (under which assumption, FOL essentially reduces to propositional logic - do you see why?).

For the second part of your question, to prove a proposed rule is not admissible, the simplest approach is to look for a counterexample, i.e., an interpretation in which the antecedent of the rule holds, but the succedent does not. Consider your first proposed rule (a):
$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash \forall x(A(x) \to B(x))}{\Gamma, \lnot B(x)\vdash \forall x \lnot A(x)}
$$
(I have tidied up your notation a bit and hope that the above is what you meant.)
To get a counter-example, we can just take $\Gamma$ to be empty and interpret $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ in the natural numbers as follows
\begin{align*}
A(x) &\equiv x = 2 \\
B(x) &\equiv x > 1
\end{align*}
Then the antecedent $\vdash \forall x (x = 2 \to x > 1)$ certainly holds, but the succedent $\lnot x > 1 \vdash \forall x(\lnot x = 2)$ does not (if we interpret the free $x$ in $\lnot x > 1$ as $1$).

For your second proposed rule (b):

$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash \forall x(A(x) \to B(x))}{\Gamma, \lnot B(x)\vdash \exists x \lnot A(x)}
$$
we can show that the rule is actually derivable (i.e., there is a fixed proof schema that shows how to derive any instance of the rule - this is a stronger property than admissibility). The details of the proof schema depend on the formulation of first-order logic you are using: the natural deduction proof schema would go something like:

\begin{align*}
1) \quad &\forall x(A(x) \to B(x)) \quad &\mbox{Conclusion of the antecedent} \\
2) \quad &A(x) \to B(x) \quad\quad&\mbox{$\forall$-elim 1}\\
3) \quad & A(x) &\mbox{Assume}\\
4) \quad& B(x) &\mbox{$\to$-elim with 2 and 3}\\
5) \quad& \lnot B(x) &\mbox{Assumption of the succedent}\\
6) \quad& \bot &\mbox{$\bot$-intro with 4 and 5}\\
7) \quad& \lnot A(x) &\mbox{$\lnot$-intro with 6 discharging 3}\\
8) \quad& \exists x\lnot A(x) &\mbox{$\exists$-intro with 7}
\end{align*}

Comment: Many, many thanks on your answer. I just have something to ask regarding your answer to my first question. Essentially, I've asked if $\Gamma \not \vdash A$ then $\Gamma \vdash A$. I thought FOL was complete in the sense that if we have a semantic proof of some formula, then we also have a proof of it. I don't think I understood why the answer is negative in this regard.

Comment: I think you have a typo/small thinko; $\forall x (x = x)$ certainly seems like it would be true in all models, not just the single-element model. Did you mean something like $\forall x\forall y (x = y)$? (And I believe the empty model would also be a valid model, of either of these.)

Comment: Sadly the word "complete" gets used for two different concepts in logic. FOL is complete in the sense that if a sentence is "semantically true" (i.e., holds in every model) then it has a proof. Soundness tells us that a sentence that is disprovable does not hold in any model. But in between those two extremes we can have sentences that are true in some models but not in others and they are neither provable nor disprovable. (There was an error in my example of this  that is now fixed. Sorry for any confusion.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: thanks - mind not concentrating on the right details. Will fix. PS. I like the concept of a "thinko" $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: as regards your point about empty models, I think that as this question is about logic rather than model theory, then empty models won't be allowed. Are first-order logics that are sound for empty models widely taught at an introductory level these days?